# Placeholder for html

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a layout component so can put other elements into it. How can I do it in VUE?

Layout component:

```
<template>
    <div>
       ###Placeholder to put others
    </div>
</template>
export default{
    name: "Layout"
}
```

Usage:

```
<template>
    <Layout>
       <p></p>
       <div></div>
       <custom-component></custom-component>
    </Layout>
</template>
export default{
    name: "SomethingElse"
}
```

Comment: use slots https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with by using slots as shown below

Layout Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <!-- the slot is where we will put the content -->
       <slot name = 'content'/>
    </div>
</template>
export default{
    name: "Layout"
}
```

Usage:

```
<template>
    <Layout>
       <!-- we now use the slot here by passing the name of the slot to the template below and putting the content inside-->
       <template #content>
         <div class='mycontent'>content</div>
       </template>
    </Layout>
</template>
export default{
    name: "SomethingElse"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).